# How can get and set on mouse click x , y position of opend pdf document?

Tags: javascript

How can get and set on mouse click  x , y position of opend pdf document ? using javascript

`function getMouseCoor() {
app.alert( "("+this.mouseX+","+ this.mouseY+")" );
}`

this code is not working

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If a PDF document is opened within the web browser, then you cannot interact with it  in Javascript.